# Eternal operation multitasking

Tags: c#, multitasking

I am studing multitasking and I came up to a very simple solution using windows form.
[image]

I have a list of object called "Car":

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Status Status { get; set; }
}

public enum Status
{
    Running,
    Standby,
    Finished
}
```

and I want to do some working in "multi sessions (tasks)".

So let's say that my "Car" have two methods: `StartFullEngine()` and `GoDrive()` that I have writen in a `CarBusiness.cs` and I want to output some messages to the `richtextbox`. I have a fixed list of 10 cars and the number of sessions will represent the number of cars going to the street (almost in the same time) but when they are in the street, they will do the same thing always. Which is:

1. `StartFullEngine()`. Once started, go to the next step:
2. `GoDrive()`. which can be performed asynchronously while another task will pick up the next car from the list and return to step 1. It stays in this loop forever but without running out of sessions.

To achieve this, here is what I did:

**CarBusiness.cs:**

```
public class CarBusiness
{
    private RichTextBox _richTextBox;
    private static readonly object syncLock = new object();
    private Car _carToRun;
    private Random random;
    public CarBusiness(Car car, RichTextBox richTextBox)
    {
        _carToRun = car;
        _richTextBox = richTextBox;
        random = new Random();
    }

    private void OutputMessage(string msg)
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            _richTextBox.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                _richTextBox.AppendText($"#{_carToRun.Id}: [{DateTime.Now.Hour.ToString("D2")}:{DateTime.Now.Minute.ToString("D2")}:{DateTime.Now.Second.ToString("D2")}] - {msg}\r\n");
            }));

        }
    }

    public Task StartFullEngine()
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var start = DateTime.Now;
            await Task.Delay(random.Next(1000, 10000));
            var end = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan timeDiff = start - end;
            var readableDiff = string.Format(
                "{0:D2} hrs, {1:D2} mins, {2:D2} secs",
                timeDiff.Hours, timeDiff.Minutes, timeDiff.Seconds);
            OutputMessage($"Full engined finished. Time ellapsed: {readableDiff}");
        });
    }

    public Task GoDrive()
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var start = DateTime.Now;
            await Foo();
            Boo().Wait();
            var end = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan timeDiff = start - end;
            var readableDiff = string.Format(
                "{0:D2} hrs, {1:D2} mins, {2:D2} secs",
                timeDiff.Hours, timeDiff.Minutes, timeDiff.Seconds);
            OutputMessage($"GoDrive() finished. Time ellapsed: {readableDiff}");
        });
    }


    private Task Foo()
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            //long operation
            OutputMessage($"Running Foo()...");
            await Task.Delay(random.Next(1000, 3000));
            OutputMessage($"Foo() ended!");
        });
    }


    private Task Boo()
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            OutputMessage($"Running Boo()...");
            await Task.Delay(random.Next(10000, 30000));
            OutputMessage($"Boo() ended!");
        });
    }
}
```

**CarDao.cs:**

```
public class CarDao
{
    public List<Car> GetListOfCar()
    {
        var list = new List<Car>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            list.Add(new Car { Id = i, Status = Status.Standby });

        return list;
    }
}
```

**Form1.cs:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private List<Car> listOfCars;
    private object objInstances = new object();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private Task<Car> GetNextCar()
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            lock (objInstances)
            {
                //Need a logic to prioritize getting cars that have never "run" before
                var nextCar = listOfCars.Where(x => x.Status != Status.Running).SkipWhile(x => x.Status == Status.Finished).FirstOrDefault();
                return nextCar;
            }
        });
    }
    private Task<List<Car>> GetInstances(Status statusCar)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            lock (objInstances)
            {
                return listOfCars.Where(x => x.Status == statusCar).ToList();
            }
        });
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var carDao = new CarDao();

        //NumericUpDown value
        var maxSessions = numberOfSessions.Value;

        //fixed list of cars
        listOfCars = carDao.GetListOfCar();

        //Never stop running
        while (true)
        {
            var runningInstances = GetInstances(Status.Running).Result;

            for (int i = runningInstances.Count(); i < maxSessions; i++)
            {
                var carToRun = GetNextCar().Result;
                carToRun.Status = Status.Running;

                var carBusiness = new CarBusiness(carToRun, richTextBox);

                Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    //First thing: StartFullEngine()
                    carBusiness.StartFullEngine().Wait();
                }).Wait();

                //After started Engine, GoDrive() can run asynchronously.
                await Task.Run(() =>
               {
                   carBusiness.GoDrive().Wait();
                   carToRun.Status = Status.Finished;
               });
                //Next loop;
            }
            //logic to wait some tasks get done to start again
            runningInstances = GetInstances(Status.Running).Result;
            if (runningInstances.Count() == maxSessions)
                Task.Delay(20000).Wait();
        }

    }
}
```

and when I run, this is the output after a couple of seconds: (seems like it's not running the way I want). Let me know if this is not clear enough.

[image]

After started Engine, `GoDrive()` can run asynchronously (go to next iteration regardless of the end of `GoDrive()`).

I expect something like this:

```
 #1: [00:23:27] - Full engined finished. Time ellapsed: 00 hrs, 00 mins, -05 secs
 //Once finished, it starts another task. (this case car #2). Now we have two tasks running, so we will until one of them finishes then get another car.
 #1: [00:23:27] - Running Foo()...
 #1: [00:23:29] - Foo() ended!
 #2: [00:23:29] - Full engined finished. Time ellapsed: 00 hrs, 00 mins, -02 secs
 #2: [00:23:29] - Running Foo()...
 #1: [00:23:29] - Running Boo()...
 #2: [00:23:31] - Running Boo()...
 #2: [00:23:32] - Boo() ended!
 #1: [00:23:52] - Boo() ended!
 #1: [00:24:15] - GoDrive() finished. Time ellapsed: 00 hrs, 00 mins, -25 secs
 //Now we have finished one task. Go to another (car #3)
 #2: [00:24:16] - GoDrive() finished. Time ellapsed: 00 hrs, 00 mins, -16 secs
 //Now we have finished one task. Go to another (car #4)
 #3: [00:24:20] - Full engined finished. Time ellapsed: 00 hrs, 00 mins, -05 secs
 #3: [00:24:21] - Running Foo()...
 #3: [00:24:25] - Foo() ended!
 #4: [00:23:27] - Full engined finished. Time ellapsed: 00 hrs, 00 mins, -05 secs
 #3: [00:24:29] - Running Foo()...
 #4: [00:23:29] - Running Boo()...
 #4: [00:23:31] - Boo() ended!
```

Comment: I can confirm that this question is not clear enough. If you can specify what you expected, and how this does not match your expectation, it will help us get to the bottom of your problem without trying to guess your intentions.

Comment: @afarley just edited the question within an expected output.

Comment: It's not really clear what you want to accomplish here. There are at least a few issues that stand out with your code, for example how you are overwriting your list of cars reference with each button click.

Comment: @StevePy I think I lacked the right words to express myself. I want'em to run in parallel.